# Duvida sobre Sessões e Roles

Tags: c#

Tenho um `controller` responsável por fazer a parte de Login, configurei no `web.config` para usar o

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Usuario/Login" timeout="30" protection="All" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

E eu gostaria que somente em algumas `ActionResult` fosse acessada por alguns usuário específicos, vi que o `[Authorize(Roles="exemplo")]` atende a minha necessidade, porém não sei como posso fazer o código para criar as sessões de perfis para usuários, por exemplo, perfil de administrador, perfil de cliente, etc. Para poder colocar na minha `Roles`.
Estou utilizando o Entity Framework e o padrão MVC.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: A documentação da Microsoft "[Role-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2)" juntamente com umas questões do **SOen**, "[MVC Role Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724798/mvc-role-authorization)", se calhar resolvem o seu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Na pasta controller, ache `ManageController`.
   Dentro deste, ache e clique em cima do `ApplicationUserManager` e aperte `F12`. Irá abrir a classe `IdentiyConfig`.
2. Acima desta classe onde você foi parar, adicione o seguinte código:

   ```
   public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
       {
           public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> store)
               : base(store)
           {
           }
           public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> 
                  options, IOwinContext context)
           {
               var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole> 
                      (context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
               return manager;
           }
       }
   ```
3. Agora, na pasta `App_Start`, abra a classe `Startup.Auth` e abaixo desta linha `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>ApplicationSignInManager.Create)`

   Adicione este código:

   ```
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
   ```
4. Volte para o `ManagerController` e abaixo disso

   ```
   private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
   ```

   Adicione isto:

   ```
   private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;
   ```
5. Abaixo do construtor, crie o seguinte:

   ```
   public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
   {
       get
       {
           return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
       }
       private set
       {
           _roleManager = value;
       }
   }
   ```
6. No construtor que tem 2 parametros, adicione mais um parametro:

   ```
   public ManageController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
   {
       UserManager = userManager;
       SignInManager = signInManager;
       RoleManager = roleManager;
   }
   ```
7. Ainda dentro do `ManageController`, crie uma `ViewModel`:

   (antes do `public class ManageController : Controller`)

   ```
   public class RoleViewModel
   {
       public string Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
8. Crie esta `ActionResult` dentro do `ManageController` (Listar)

   ```
   public ActionResult Roles()
   {
       var roles = RoleManager.Roles.ToList();
       return View(roles.Select(x => new RoleViewModel() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }));
   }
   ```
9. Crie a `View` desta como `List` e usando a `ViewModel` criada anteriormente. Não esqueça de trocar o Create por CreateRole aqui:

   ```
   @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateRole")
   ```
10. Crie esta `ActionResult` dentro do `ManageController` (Cadastrar)

    ```
    public ActionResult CreateRole()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateRole(RoleViewModel model)
    {
        if (RoleManager.RoleExists(model.Name))
        {
            //Retorna erro, informando que ja existe essa Role
        }
        var newRole = new IdentityRole(model.Name);
        var result = RoleManager.Create(newRole);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Roles");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
    ```
11. Crie a `View` desta como `Create` e usando a `ViewModel` criada anteriormente.
12. Crie esta `ActionResult` dentro do `ManageController` (Adicionar Role a Usuario)

    ```
    public ActionResult AddRoleToUser()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddRoleToUser(string user, string role)
    {
        var _user = UserManager.FindByEmail(user);
        var _role = RoleManager.FindByName(role);
        var result = UserManager.AddToRole(_user.Id, role);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Roles");
        }
        ViewBag.Erro = result.Errors;
        return View();
    }
    ```
13. Crie a `View` desta como `Create` e usando a `ViewModel` criada anteriormente. Façamos algumas alterações nessa `View`: Mude os campos do formulario:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Usuario", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.Editor("user", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>

    @Html.Label("Role", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.Editor("role", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</div>
```

14. Ainda dentro desta `View`, crie a exibição do `ViewBag.Erro`:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddRoleToUser";
    var erros = ViewBag.Erro as IEnumerable<String>;
}

<h2>AddRoleToUser</h2>

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in erros)
    {
        <li>@item</li>
    }
</ul>
```

15. Para finalizar, adicione a anotação na `View` que deseja fazer a verificação da role:

    ```
    [Authorize(Roles = "RoleQueCriar")]
    public ActionResult Pagina(){ return View(); }
    ```

Aprendi isso neste vídeo e até hoje faço desta forma!!

Fonte: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylmHZwAl9Hc